# handle single quota in text file using sscanf

Tags: c

I going to split up the text

```
Central & Western - Water Street,6799,660,2780,1901,2624
Wan Chai - Hennessy,6505,766,1606,2071,2725
Wan Chai - Oi Kwan,6232,737,1919,2696,2651
Wan Chai - Canal Road,7607,982,2021,2913,3083
Wan Chai - Causeway Bay,6311,819,1387,2324,3275
Wan Chai - Tai Hang,6856,899,2148,1949,2725
Wan Chai - Jardine's Lookout,6567,1103,2940,1973,2029
Wan Chai - Broadwood,6101,1397,2887,1730,2080
Wan Chai - Happy Valley,6684,881,1550,2056,2418
```

The code

```
sscanf(line_buffer, "%[^','],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", node.district, &node.employees, &node.employers, &node.students, &node.retried, &node.others);
```

But at Jardine's, the single quota seems break my program, how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the quotes from your expression (they are not needed):

```
"%[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d"
```